# How to pass a value in href into modal window in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have displayed a listing in laravel from table given as below:

```
       <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    @php $sln = 1 @endphp

                    @foreach ($roles as $role)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $sln++ }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $role->name }}</td>
                            <td><a href="" class="btn addbtn editrole" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#role-edit-modal">Edit</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

I have also a modal form in bootstrap on clicking on the `<a>` Edit which is given below.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="role-edit-modal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Role</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="formbox">
                    <form action="" method="post" id="role-form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="roleName">Role Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="role-name" class="form-control" maxlength="50" value="{{ old('email', $role->name) }}">
                            <span id="role-error" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btngroup">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wanted to pass the value of `$role->id` from `to this modal file and display the value in`$role->name`

How do I passw the value of `id` on clicking the edit button in jQuery and trigger the modal window.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Jquery or JS for this

```
<td>
    <a href="#" data-id="{{$role->id}}" class="btn addbtn editrole">Edit</a>
</td>

$('.addbtn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('#role-edit-modal').modal('show');
    alert(id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

View:

```
<td><a href="" class="btn addbtn editrole" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#role-edit-modal" onclick="getRoleDetails('{{$role->id}}', '{{$role->name}}');" >Edit</a></td>
```

JS:

```
function getRoleDetails (roleId, roleName) {

   // If you want to display the role ID

   document.getElementById('role-name').value = roleId;


   // If you want to display the role name

   document.getElementById('role-name').value = roleName;

}
```